# Unable to install Ubuntu 14.0 alongside windows 8.1 in lenovo g580

Tags: software-installation

Every one i have Lenovo G580 laptop which came without any operating system then i installed windows 8.1 and now trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 along side but the option in the Ubuntu installation does not shows windows 8.1 installed instead it suggests to install erase everything and install ...

please give me suggestions how to install Ubuntu alongside windows 8.1
thank you..
waiting for the suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps this guide will help you http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/

Answer (score 1):

At that screen there must be `Something Else` item besides `Erase disk and install Ubuntu`. Here you select manually partitioning. You can add/create (from free unallocated space) or delete partitions but not resize them from the Ubuntu installation. If you didn't resize (don't have free unallocated space enough to create new partition) then run Gparted from  Ubuntu - you can select `Try Ubuntu` not `Install Ubuntu` and run Gparted from ther. Or you can resize your Windows partition (if needed) from Windows before running Ubuntu installation. If in windows, there is free utility called `Partition Wizard`. http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html